# Unable to access variable within a function in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, function, socket.io

In the function I'm building a socket method but I can't access pCount after the socket method in the function

[image: Code]

Use of unresolved identifier 'pCount'
Why?

Comment: You created **pCount** as local variable. Because of this reason you are not accessing **pCount**. Declare as **global** variable.

Comment: Notice that pCount is inside a pair of `{ }`. So it can't escape from inside that scope.

Comment: @jtbandes Is there anyway I can get pCount out of that scope?

Comment: It depends. What is `socket.on`? Is it asynchronous? What are you trying to do? What libraries are you using? This question doesn't have enough information to be useful. Please read [ask]

Comment: @jtbandes it is socket.io and I'm using SocketIOClientSwift as the library, yes it is asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

psCount is async function so you can't return in it. In  case, socket.on have't finished but psCount is still return
You should  code:

```
func psCount(handleFinish:((pCount:Int)->())){
    socket.on("reply") { data, act in
        let json = Json(data)
        let pCount:Int = json[0].count
        handleFinish(pCount: pCount:Int)
    }
}
```

and call it:

```
self.psCount { (pCount) -> () in
        print(pCount)
    }
```